# Cannot login to Philips Hue developer account

Tags: account, activation, philips-hue

- I registered an account with https://developers.meethue.com/login/
- verified my email
- attempted to login, but it said I have incorrect password
- I used the "Forgot password" to reset the password
- gave a new password (which is 1 character less than the original 30 characters)
- got a message that the password was successfully reset
- But now when I try to login again with the new credentials, it says "Your account is awaiting e-mail verification."

I didn't any new emails for activating, and the link in the old activation email has already expired. There is no option to trigger a resend.

How do I activate my account?

Comment: I have the same problem...  been waiting for 1 hour now..

Comment: Same problem here